# .focus and .trigger with text

Tags: text, triggers, click, focus

I need help with my script. Need script working like this:

```
$(".Chat textarea").val(pQ); < .chat textarea [text place], pQ < my text
```

I want when text add in .chat textarea when add `.focus()` and press AUTO ENTER. 
I think this script must look like:

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
e.which = 13; //choose the one you want
e.keyCode = 13;
$(".Chat textarea").val(pQ);$(".Chat textarea").focus();$(".Chat textarea".trigger(e);
```

I try this but this not work :/